# How to extract values from an MS Access form using COM?

Tags: api, vba, com, autohotkey

I have an MS Access form, which is write protected and I am unable to query the underlying database. What I need is to read the values presented in lables in an MS Access form using COM. How could this be achieved. I am programming in Autohotkey, but help in any language is useful.

There is useful information on how to do the same for MS Word at: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic31923.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any experience with programming macros for office in VBA, this helps Autohotkey COM development a lot, as you're running the same commands with a different syntax.

```
Dim newThing as var
Set newThing = oThing.GetThing()
```

becomes

```
newThing := COM_Invoke(oThing, "GetThing")
```

The examples on the forum are great for seeing how the syntax translates between VBA and Autohotkey COM.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of using COM, if you only need to get the values out of labels, consider using `ControlGetText`, a built-in Autohotkey function. You can use WindowSpy to get the control names and `ControlGetText` to retrieve the text out of them.